# RoboVM Couldn't create build dir

Tags: java, ios, libgdx, robovm

I am trying to port my (already in development) LibGDX app to iOS. The way I attempted to do this is by creating a new LibGDX project so I could have a template for the iOS module code that I need (ex. the IOSLauncher class) as well as formatting for the gradle scripts. After doing this, the gradle synced properly and there are no syntax errors. However, when I go to build my project using the RoboVM plugin, I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Couldn't compile app
java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't create build dir '/robovm-build/tmp/ios/ios/x86'
at org.robovm.idea.RoboVmPlugin.getModuleBuildDir(RoboVmPlugin.java:591)
at org.robovm.idea.compilation.RoboVmCompileTask.compileForRunConfiguration(RoboVmCompileTask.java:185)
at org.robovm.idea.compilation.RoboVmCompileTask.execute(RoboVmCompileTask.java:78)
at com.intellij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver.executeCompileTasks(CompileDriver.java:628)
at com.intellij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver.access$400(CompileDriver.java:92)
at com.intellij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver$3.run(CompileDriver.java:428)
at com.intellij.compiler.progress.CompilerTask.run(CompilerTask.java:196)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any ideas as to why it wouldn't be able to create that build directory?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Android studio you're using?